# Horizontal Menubar UL LI width fix - using hacks / fixing width - which is preferable?

Tags: html, html-lists

1) Horizontal menu-bar is created using UL LI and width of each menu (LI) is created/fixed using margin and padding. This creates compatibility issues in IE browsers (obviously). By fixing them using IF conditional statements, Chrome and Safari differs with 1px i.e. compatibility issues increases and need to fix them using hacks.

2) To solve all this, if I give width to each LI, my menu-bar works in all browsers without any compatibility fix.

Though, I am not very much fond of using hacks, sometimes for small fixes, I used them. Mostly, html developers go with 1st option, I need to know which approach is better.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I don't generally need hacks when making menus like this - maybe if you post your code, we can have a look :)

Comment: Hi Zenkaty - My query is general and clear. Hence no need to add any code for this. Just need to know which approach should get used for better usage. I know each option has its own benefit. However, just for curiosity, need to know experts choice, if any.